# Assigning a New Owner

Tags: solidity, function

I am writing a contact that sets a new owner as per below but cannot understand why the function setNewOwner needs to be a view function. I would have thought assigning a new owner would change the state so would not require a visability function?

```
mapping (address => uint) balanceAllowance;
address public owner; 

constructor () {
    owner = msg.sender;
}

function setNewOwner (address _address) public view {
    owner == _address;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you put comparator operator `==` there, you should have used `=`.

#### More Explanation

Since you used `==` function checks if `owner` and `_address` equals and does not do any change so your editor suggests you to change it to view. If you have put a `return` there like below

```
function setNewOwner (address _address) public view {
    return owner == _address;
}
```

It would return true.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add that you should notice that anyone can call this function and set it’s owner after you’ll switch `owner == _address` To `owner = _address`.

Consider using `msg.sender`